# Prevent usage of existing method in Scala

Tags: scala

Can I prevent calling selected methods from existing Java/Scala classes at compile time? So the code which tries to call the forbidden method won't compile.

I have an existing Scala class (from external library) with the following method

`def saveToDb[A](a: A)`

but unfortunately it throws exception when `a` cannot be saved to database. Since I want to detect this condition at compile time I can write

`def safeSaveToDb[A: CanBeSavedToDb](a: A)`

where type class instance guarantees that `a` can be saved to database and no exception is thrown. Is now possible to prevent usage of `saveToDb`.

Comment: Try making the `class A` members `transient`

Comment: If you are using Maven as build tool then you can use `pmd` for setting usage rules.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh maybe that's the way to go if I don't find any solution how to do it in Scala

Answer (score 1):

If I've understood correctly, you need to have an interface which will be your polymorphic functions type bound.

eg

```
   trait CanBeSaved {
      def toDataToBeSaved: String //this is just an example
   }

   //then your bounds like so

   final def saveToDb[A <: CanBeSaved](a: A): Future[Unit] = save(a)

   def save(json: String): Future[Unit]
```

This will ensure at compile time that only objects which extend `CanBeSaved` are saved.

I hope this helps,
Rhys

Comment: Yeah, I can do this but there is still an unsafe function from external library which doesn't support `CanBeSaved` and I want somehow to hide this function so me and other programmers don't accidentally use it.

Comment: Make it final :)

Comment: Also, you couldn't override it if the bounds aren't conforming. otherwise it wouldn't actually be overridable

Comment: The problem is that `saveToDb` is from the external library and I cannot modify it. I just wrote a safer function `safeSaveToDb` and I want to prevent using the original unsafe function.

Comment: Extend the class?